# Having difficulty creating a singular controller (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a model and controller without an "s" but I keep getting this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation 
"holistic_feedbacks" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"holistic_feedbacks"'::re...
                                      ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, 
a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
         (SELECT c.collname FROM pg_collation c, pg_type t
           WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid = a.atttypid AND 
a.attcollation <> t.typcollation),
                 col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
            FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
              ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"holistic_feedbacks"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum
):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails assumes you're going to follow convention.  When you don't, you need to tell it you're straying off the path.  If you've already run your migrations and you know the table exists, it needs to be told the table is actually "holistic_feedback".  To do so, go in your model file `models/holistic_feedback.rb` and add:

```
self.table_name = "holistic_feedback"
```